# How to load resources in a different culture than the current thread's culture?

Tags: .net, silverlight, localization, windows-phone-8

I need to load resources in a windows phone application (Silverlight) from a different culture than the current thread's culture (to handle some operations that I need to do on phone's language change).

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ResourceManager` has an overloaded version of the `GetObject()` method which accepts a `CultureInfo` object.

So you would create this object based on the culture you want and pass it along:

```
CultureInfo enCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
ResourceManager.GetObject("objectname", enCulture);
```

Comment: Nice, but these methods does not exist in Silverlight :(

Comment: At the end I had to use a ResourceManager instance with some constructor parameters but anyway you answer is the best one (and as usual on current times the only one ... :S)